# Crystal oscillator circuit

Tags: adc, clock

I am using following circuit and crystal is connected to XTAL2 and XTAL1 pin as shown below.

Following IC is LPC2138, shown in image.

[image: crystal]

I am using ADC chip ( DDC112 ) for A to D conversion. For ADC IC, CLK pin is needed. If I want to use same crystal (Y1 in the image) for ADC, I need to assign this pin to CLK pin of ADC.

Which pin should I connect to CLK pin of ADC, XTAL2 or XTAL1 (if crystal frequncy is same for both chip) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use XTAL2 as your ADC's clock source, but you may need a buffer between XTAL2 and your ADC's CLK pin, such as a Schmitt-trigger 74HC1G14.

---

Update:

As the OP's question in comment:

> Why 74HC1G14 is needed?

Per LPC2183's datasheet, XTAL2's output voltage ranges from -0.5V to 1.95V. This voltage level may not high enough to drive your ADC's CLK input. And this may also slow down the edge rate of the clock signal.

Comment: Why 74HC1G14 is needed? How will be the connection? I am completely newbie for this, so sorry for stupid question.

Comment: @Techknowlogic: See my updated answer.